# Expression must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map an object with difficult structure to a simple object:

```
 public class Contact
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
public class Phone
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public PhoneType Type { get; set; }
}


public enum PhoneType
{
    Phone,
    Mobile
}

public class ContactDto
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}

 Mapper.CreateMap<ContactDto, Contact>()
                .ForMember(p => p.Phones.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Type.Equals(PhoneType.Mobile)).Number, r => r.MapFrom(s => s.MobileNumber))
                .ForMember(p => p.Phones.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Type.Equals(PhoneType.Phone)).Number, r => r.MapFrom(s => s.PhoneNumber));
```

But I have an error in the title. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your generic parameters is wrong. The source should be the first and the destination is the latter.

Try this instead:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactDto>()
       .ForMember(dto => dto.PhoneNumber, dto => dto.MapFrom(src => src.Phones.First(p => p.Type == PhoneType.Phone).Number))
       .ForMember(dto => dto.MobileNumber, dto => dto.MapFrom(src => src.Phones.First(p => p.Type == PhoneType.Mobile).Number));
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats work. But if I need to map from ContactDto into Contact?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to create another mapping. Automatic `ReverseMap()` is intended for basic cases and I don't think AutoMapper can ever infer (from your current mapping) that whenever you need to map from `ContactDto` to `Contact`, it should create 2 `Phone` entries in the `Phones` list, each from another property in the DTO.